# 301 redirect Domain Name using global.asax from domainname.com to www.domainname.com

Tags: asp.net, azure, http-status-code-301, global-asax

My problem is such that on my www page I have an error 404 from azure but I am just enter domainname.com then works since without problems

I would like it to be called:

domainname.com and do while to www.domainname.com going to work and not come up with 404 errors.

i have try its her in **global.asax**

```
protected void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string currentUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Path.ToLower();
  if(currentUrl.StartsWith("http://mydomain"))
  {
    Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
    Response.AddHeader("Location", currentUrl.Replace("http://mydomain", "http://www.mydomain"));
    Response.End();
  }
}
```

**Note: after mydomain must stand .com**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of writing code which requires a postback. You can configure your domain pointer on your domain host to redirect automatically to the proper path.

Should be similar to this: 
http://www.networksolutions.com/support/how-to-set-up-domain-pointers/